# Meteor 1.2.0.2 - Couldn't run tasklist.exe on Windows 10

Tags: meteor, tasklist

I just recently downloaded meteor and started the first tutorial where it has you make a todo list. When it came to running my code, command prompt popped up with this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Rhys>cd ./desktop/simple-todos

C:\Users\Rhys\Desktop\simple-todos>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\Rhys\Desktop\simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

C:\Users\Rhys\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.9\mt-os.windows.x86
_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: tasklist wasn't found on your system, it usual
ly can be found at C:\Windows\System32\.
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Rhys\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-t
ool\1.1.9\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:
15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:134:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:279:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:4
00:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:656:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:7
56:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:714:10)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-all.js:168:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:84:24
    at exithandler (child_process.js:654:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:670:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)

C:\Users\Rhys\Desktop\simple-todos>
```

I went into the location C:\Windows\System32, and tasklist.exe was indeed there.

I tried a bunch of things that were online, but couldn't really find a clear answer. I also tried reinstalling the program, but that also didn't work.

Would appreciate it a bunch if you could help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting from the terminal.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I tried posting a picture, but i need "10 reputation" to post and  image (according to StackOverflow).

Comment: if you open up a command prompt, from the root, can you type tasklist.exe and will it then run?

Comment: @Wobbles Yes it does

Comment: @Wobbles, just checked the definition of root and was mistaken of what it is. I ran it again (in the actual root) and it pops up saying that it is not recognized as an operable program or batch file.

Comment: ok, so then sounds like your system 32 may not be defined as in your path environmental variables, give that a check.

Comment: @Wobbles, It worked!! Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't mind then, I am going to post as an answer so I can w#0re that stackoverflow reputation lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your system32 folder is stored in your environment variables under `path`. This env variable tells Windows and subsequent command line arguments that if the command (.exe .bat. cmd) does not exist in the working directory, to check the directories in the `path` variable to see if they exist there. This is how command line commands such as `ipconfig` work from any directory.